# How do I change the placeholder color of <input> that it is inside <mat-form-field> from angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-form-field

I am trying to change the placeholder color to WHITE on my input element using .CSS.
 element it is inside

```
  <mat-form-field class="text-center">
    <input class="daniel" matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="Search-bar">
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: What have you tried? How about a stackblitz example?

Answer (score 0):

Angular Material component colors relies on themes. This means that you can create a custom theme to make this work.
Have a look at how to create a theme if this could help:
https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Another solution could be overwriting the css style but I do currently hold the knowledge for the placeholder inside the input component

Answer (score 0):

Theming is the correct way to color material components, however, if you want to manually override the label in a material input, you can do so like this:

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-focused .mat-form-field-label {
    color:white;
}
```

https://stack59148369.stackblitz.io